# Why popover's title displays badly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-window

I'm using bootstrap in my project. I would like to use popover inside of modal window, but popover's title look like this:

[image]

Here is code I have inside of modal:

```
<button id="popover-test-in-modal" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
   data-toggle="popover" title="Test for popover" 
   data-content="And here's some amazing content. Testing popover.">Popover
</button>

<script>
        $("#popover-test-in-modal").popover();
</script>
```

Here is jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7k5mjw24/

How can I fix it?

Comment: If you have other styles than bootstrap on your page they could be overriding the bootstrap classes. Posting a jsFiddle will be best.

Comment: your popover looks all okay.. [JS fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/us5L18nz/), try refering the bootstrap css in the last

Comment: I have style from template I bought. In jsFiddle everything works. I'll post it in couple minutes.

Comment: Its look like that your header tag is getting width tag applied from template. Try by applying width:100% !important for this modal tooltip header tag. Hope it works

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: can you add your template CSS into the fiddle so it can be more helpful

Comment: Fidlle is updated with template css.